# CFWriteStreamSetProperty is returning false for kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings

Tags: iphone, sockets, networking, ssl, ios

Hey, I'm attempting to setup SSL for my server protocol. Anyways, when I go to set the kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, it returns false. Not sure why.

Here's my sslDict:

```
2010-11-04 15:48:59.742
bytestest[30897:207] sslDict = {
    kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot = 1;
    kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates = 1;
    kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots = 1;
    kCFStreamSSLCertificates =     (
        "<SecIdentityRef: 0x792ede0>",
        "<SecTrustRef: 0x792f220>"
    );
    kCFStreamSSLLevel = kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL;
}
```

Here's the code I'm talking about:

```
isPropertySet = CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream,
                                         kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, 
                                         sslDict);
```

After this line isPropertySet is set to false

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in the trust where the cert should have been!